# How to add text and button in bootstrap modal footer?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add some text in the bootstrap modal footer, however the output looks like 2 divs side by side which I don't want. Below is the code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="itiModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Day Wise data</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        Entire or partial data collected from Wikipedia.
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the output looks like this:
[image: unexpected]
I want the text to appear below the buttons. I've tried putting the text in P/span tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on questioner want to make buttons align right and text below and left align:

[image]

heres full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .modal-footer{display: block}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Bootstrap 4</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itiModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
</div>
  

  <div class="modal fade" id="itiModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Day Wise data</h4>
          
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Bookmark</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Details</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
          <p class="text-left">Entire or partial data collected from Wikipedia.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add css code to modal footer: `.modal-footer{ display: block }`

[image]

here's full code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .modal-footer{display: block}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Bootstrap 4</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itiModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
</div>
  

  <div class="modal fade" id="itiModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Day Wise data</h4>
          
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Bookmark</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Details</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <p>Entire or partial data collected from Wikipedia.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the buttons to be right aligned and the text to be left aligned in the footer.

Comment: How's that! you said literally (I want the text to appear below the buttons.)

Comment: Yes, in your pic the text is left aligned, but the buttons are left aligned too. I want the button to be right aligned. and the text to be left aligned below the buttons.

Comment: check here modal https://i.imgur.com/3NfzvrZ.png

Comment: My output is same as the pic you posted above, I want something like this https://imgur.com/a/bt8U7Mn

Comment: its done I will make new answer and keep first answer for who wants text below the buttons! :)